# compiling errors of ofxmotiontracker ofxaddon

Tags: openframeworks

I am trying to use the ofxMotionTracker add on for openframeworks.
I am building it in codeblocks over linux 64 architecture.

While building it I get compilation errors in ofCircleSlice.cpp

```
void ofCircleSlice(float x,float y, float radius, float lowAngle, float highAngle, bool closed, bool radians){

if (!bSetupCircle) setupCircle();

// use smoothness, if requested:
if (bSmoothHinted && drawMode == OF_OUTLINE) startSmoothing();

bool angleWrap = (lowAngle > highAngle); // are we doing the 0/360 wrap?

if(!radians){
    lowAngle = ofDegToRad(lowAngle);
    highAngle = ofDegToRad(highAngle);
}

int res = numCirclePts;
float angle = lowAngle;
float angleRange = ((!angleWrap)?(highAngle - lowAngle):(M_TWO_PI - lowAngle + highAngle));
float angleAdder = angleRange / (float)res;
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numCirclePts; i++){
    circlePtsScaled[k] = x + cos(angle) * radius;
    circlePtsScaled[k+1] = y - sin(angle) * radius;
    angle += angleAdder;
    k+=2;
}
// we draw the circle points ourself (vs. glDrawArrays) because it allows us to draw the center point, and have the triangles fan around it
k = 0;
glBegin((drawMode == OF_FILLED) ? GL_TRIANGLE_FAN : (closed?GL_LINE_LOOP:GL_LINE_STRIP));
glVertex2f(x, y); // center vertex

// now all the points around the circumference
for (int i = 0; i < numCirclePts; i++){
    glVertex2f(circlePtsScaled[k], circlePtsScaled[k+1]);
    k+=2;
}
glEnd();

    // back to normal, if smoothness is on
    if (bSmoothHinted && drawMode == OF_OUTLINE) endSmoothing();
};
```

Errors Obtained are:

> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp||In
> function ‘void ofCircleSlice(float, float, float, float, float, bool,
> bool)’:|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|6|error:
> ‘bSetupCircle’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|6|error:
> ‘setupCircle’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|9|error:
> ‘bSmoothHinted’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|9|error:
> ‘drawMode’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|9|error:
> ‘startSmoothing’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|18|error:
> ‘numCirclePts’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|24|error:
> ‘circlePtsScaled’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|32|error:
> ‘drawMode’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|37|error:
> ‘circlePtsScaled’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|43|error:
> ‘bSmoothHinted’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ../../../addons/ofxMotionTracker-master/src/ofCircleSlice.cpp|43|error:
> ‘endSmoothing’ was not declared in this scope|
>
> ||=== Build finished:  11 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Am I missing something very obvious here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced ofCircleSlice function with the following code

```
  ofPath tArcPath;
tArcPath.setArcResolution(360);
tArcPath.arc(x, y, radius, radius, lowAngle, highAngle);
tArcPath.draw();
```

no build errors & worked fine